# Regex may contains a group or not

Tags: regex

I have multiple string to parse. This text could be multiline or not. 
Also, some part may not be exist. I have some samples to understand what I need.

Samples;
1-singleline)  00026A123456123456789012741852
2-multiline)   00030A789ABC210987654321258369X123

X is seperate groups.
I try to use this regex: `(?<group1>.*)(?:[X](?<group2>.*))`

Comment: Try [`^(?<group1>.*?)(?:X(?<group2>.*))?$`](https://regex101.com/r/hpScrj/2). Does the *last* `X` separate the groups, or the first one? Or can there be just 1 `X`?

Comment: Thanks but not working for first one. First one has no second group. My demo https://regex101.com/r/BJdSUb/1

Comment: What do you mean by "no second group"? It is empty. How are you using the regex? Do not believe what you see at regex101, it does not display non-participating groups. It is regex101 bug.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, I have no idea about this bug, regex works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there can be only 1 `X` separating the groups, or it is the first `X` that always separates the groups, you may use

```
^(?<group1>.*?)(?:X(?<group2>.*))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hpScrj/3).

The first group pattern should be a lazy dot `.*?` and the second one should be wrapped with an optional non-capturing group `(?:....)?`.

When the text has no `X...`, the second capturing group is considered *non-participating*, and thus is either *null* or *empty* (depending on where you use the regex).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?<group1>.*?)` - any 0+ chars (or excluding linebreak symbols, depending on the regex engine) as few as possible up to the first
- `(?:X(?<group2>.*))?` -  an optional sequence of `X` followed with any 0+ chars as many as possible up to
- `$`  - the end of string.